# LINQ to check whether a list<Roles> is subset of another list<Roles>

Tags: c#, linq

I am having two list of Users class i.e UsersExisting, UsersToUpdate.
Class Structure is like below.

```
public class Users
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Roles[] AvailableRoles{get;set;}
}

class Roles
{
    public int Serial{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public bool IsActive{get;set;}
}
```

I have to check whether UsersToUpdate has already all the Role details of UsersExisting.

Eg. This is the list

```
UsersExisting.AvailableRoles={{1,"admin",true},{2,"hr",false},{3,"it",true}};
UsersToUpdate.AvailableRoles={{1,"admin",true},{2,"hr",false},{3,"it",true},{4,"finance",false}};
```

How to do this with LINQ.

I am doing like this.

```
bool isUsersUpdated = !UsersExisting.AvailableRoles
.Except(UsersToUpdate.AvailableRoles).Any();
```

This is throwing error.

Comment: what error did you see?

Comment: can you post the error as well

Comment: I know I am doing wrong. Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: What you have posted doesn't throw an error (provided you fix the compile time issues)

Comment: you are missing `;` after every `set` keyword.

Comment: thanks for pointing out syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the `Serial` numbers with `Except` which seem to be the role-identifiers:

```
IEnumerable<int> existingRoles = UsersExisting
    .SelectMany(u => u.AvailableRoles.Select(r => r.Serial));
IEnumerable<int> updatingRoles = UsersToUpdate
   .SelectMany(u => u.AvailableRoles.Select(r => r.Serial));
bool isUsersUpdated = !existingRoles.Except(updatingRoles).Any();
```

> I have to compare both serial number and Name.

then the best approach is to override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` in `Roles` or to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Roles>` which you can pass to `Enumerable.Except`. Another way is to use my code but select an anonymous type containing the serial+name:

```
IEnumerable<int> existingRoles = UsersExisting
    .SelectMany(u => u.AvailableRoles.Select(r => new {r.Serial,r.Name}));
IEnumerable<int> updatingRoles = UsersToUpdate
    .SelectMany(u => u.AvailableRoles.Select(r => new {r.Serial,r.Name}));
bool isUsersUpdated = !existingRoles.Except(updatingRoles).Any();
```

Comment: I have to compare both serial number and Name.

Comment: @Veer Are you saying that role 1 isn't always going to be "admin"? That sounds like pretty bad design.

Comment: I am learning C# and LInQ, it has nothing to do with design right now.

Comment: @Veer: then the best approach is to override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` in `Roles` or to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Roles>` which you can pass to `Enumerable.Except`. Another way is to use my code but select an anonymous type containing the serial+name. **Updated my answer**

Answer (score 1):

You have to override methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class `Roles` to make this work. This is because `Except` uses these methods to determine whether objects are equal to each other.

See how to override these methods here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare sequences of objects of some custom data type, implement the IEquatable generic interface in your class. Also, You have to override the Equals and GetHashCode method in Roles class.

I have created [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DKlcln) dotnet fiddle here. You can see the output of program.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var availbleRoles = new List<Roles>();
        availbleRoles.Add(new Roles() { Serial = 1, Name = "Test 1", IsActive = true });    
        availbleRoles.Add(new Roles() { Serial = 2, Name = "Test 2", IsActive = true });    
        availbleRoles.Add(new Roles() { Serial = 4, Name = "Test 4", IsActive = true });    


        var updatedRoles = new List<Roles>();
        updatedRoles.Add(new Roles() { Serial = 1, Name = "Test 1", IsActive = true }); 
        updatedRoles.Add(new Roles() { Serial = 2, Name = "Test 2", IsActive = true }); 
        updatedRoles.Add(new Roles() { Serial = 3, Name = "Test 3", IsActive = true }); 
        updatedRoles.Add(new Roles() { Serial = 4, Name = "Test 4", IsActive = true });


        var roles = updatedRoles.Except(availbleRoles);
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Serial : " + role.Serial + " Name : " + role.Name);
        }

        bool isRoleUpdated = roles.Any();

        Console.WriteLine("Role Updated : " + isRoleUpdated);
    }
}

public class Roles : System.IEquatable<Roles>
{
    public int Serial {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}

    public bool Equals(Roles other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return Serial.Equals(other.Serial) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashRoleName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();

        // Get hash code for the Serial field.
        int hashSerial = Serial.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the Role.
        return hashSerial ^ hashRoleName;
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Roles[] AvailableRoles { get; set; }
}
```